# Checkout repository based on Tag in the Jenkins Workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

With the [Jenkins Workflow Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin), I can checkout a repository based on branch. However, I would like to checkout a repository based on a tag.

This is my current configuration for checking out the master branch

```
node {
    git url: src, branch: 'master'
}
```

Now I would like to achieve to check out tag 3.6.1. I tried to change the branch to a tag, but that won't work. Neither is there something in the documentation regarding checking out on tag.

Is this currently possible? Am I overseeing something?

references;

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/scm-step/README.md

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/scm-step/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/scm/GitStep/config.jelly

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/scm-step/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/scm/GitStep.java

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just found the answer myself by crawling through the issue list. Seems like they won't change it; https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27018

This is the suggested solution;

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: src]], branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/3.6.1']]], poll: false
```

Comment: What if I want it to accept both branch name as well as tag?

Comment: @ShivangiBhardwaj, as far as git is concerned both branches (ref/heads) and tags (ref/tags) are just pointers to a commit. In particular, you cannot have a tag related to a specific branch. Therefore your question does not make sens (in Git terms); you can ask Jenkins to either checkout a branch head or tag but not both at the same time.

Comment: this works, but it's a little long, how to make it multiple lines?

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoURL, 
credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false
```

Not This:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoURL], 
[credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false
```

Comment: the only difference is the ], [ in userRemoteConfigs parameter

Answer (score 3):

`noTags: false` does the trick.

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: githash ]],
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
     extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', 
     depth: 0, 
     noTags: false,
```